# Simple htaccess conversion

Tags: .htaccess

I am a novice to htaccess 
I want to translate 
http://localhost/hawaii/index.php?city=arizona

to 
http://localhost/hawaii/arizona

Any instant help will be very great for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file in your site's root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^/]+)/index\.php\?city=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/index.php?city=$2 [QSA,L]
```